# Подключение шрифта и Opera 9.64

Tags: css, шрифты, opera, кроссбраузерность

В opera 9.64 не подключается шрифт.

```
@font-face {
 font-family: 'PT Sans';
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 400;
 src: local('PT Sans'), local('PTSans-Regular'),
  url(../fonts/37660512ac27f770b4231a4d31c0ae96.eot),
  url(../fonts/37660512ac27f770b4231a4d31c0ae96.eot?#iefix) format('embedded-opentype'),
  url(../fonts/37660512ac27f770b4231a4d31c0ae96.woff) format('woff'),
  url(../fonts/37660512ac27f770b4231a4d31c0ae96.ttf) format('truetype'),
  url(../fonts/37660512ac27f770b4231a4d31c0ae96.svg) format('svg');
}
```

Скорее всего из-за того, что не поддерживается в ней CSS3 (@font-face).

В консоли никаких ошибок нет. Это как-то исправимо?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Действительно, в `Opera 9.64` [согласно официальной документации движка Presto](http://www.opera.com/docs/specs/) еще не реализована поддержка CSS `font-face`, она появляется с версии `Presto 2.2` а это `Opera 10.0/Opera Mobile 9.7` И то, судя по отзывам она ужасно глючит в 10-11 версиях.

Правда если это как-то поможет, [частично поддерживается](http://www.opera.com/docs/specs/opera95/svg/) `font-face` для `svg`, то есть Вы можете попробовать загрузить `svg`-шрифт для текста внутри `svg`. На этом решения которые мне удалось найти, заканчиваются.

Если у мсье много свободного времени и любви к искусству, он может детектить версию браузера и при виде старой оперы показывать версию с контентом засунутым внутрь `svg`. Главное детям это не показывайте.

Comment: впринципе так и подозревал. Но ладно, что поделать. Тогда вручу 50 очков через 20 часов, как пишет система.

Answer (score 3):

`@font-face` доступен в ранних версиях `CSS`. Попробуйте указать абсолютный путь для подключаемых шрифтов. Также есть мнение, что `Opera` отказывается подключать шрифты когда имя пользователя Windows написано кириллицей.

Comment: Как понять "абсолютный путь"?

Comment: @ModaL От корня сайта: example.com/fonts/arial.ttf как `url(/fonts/arial.ttf)`

Comment: к сожалению, но не помогло. Консоль по font-face не выдаёт ошибок, что очень странно.

Comment: попробуйте заключить url в кавычки

Comment: @OlegUP, кавычки-не кавычки - другие кавычки, это все пляски по мертвецу если в спеке написано что поддержки нету)